# How can I make ROC and compute AUC?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, probability, boosting, ensemble

I created a boosting tree and got the probability for each tuple in my testing set. But I'm confused on how to combine each probability. Can someone tell me how to combine the probabilities?

[image: Adaboost]

Comment: You have to have the real $Y$ value

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question should be asked in cross validated

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean? @Mark.F

Comment: what do you mean by real value? the ground truth? I have. -1 or 1. @JuanEstebandelaCalle

Comment: Yes, is against that variable what you compare the probability with (normally is 0,1)

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by against? Can you elaborate please? @JuanEstebandelaCalle

Comment: AUC and ROC are functions that compare probabilities taken from models you ran against the real data you have as $Y$ in your database.

Comment: @JuanEstebandelaCalle Thank you, but my question is, I try to make ensemble classifier, not just a single tree. In my example I have two trees (M1 and M2). To get the final prediction I need to combine the two probabilities in each tree. How can I combine those probabilities?

Answer (score 1):

Is an interesting question.

You are solving a optimization problem

$max$
$AUC(\alpha_1*X_1 + \alpha_2*X_2,Y)$

$s.t.$
$\sum^2_{i=1}\alpha = 1$

You are maximizing the AUC using the models 1 and 2 (which are $X_1$ and $X_2$) subject to the sum of weights is 1.

You may any optimization algorithm, even Excel's solver to do this.